# I want to remove(export) duplicates from multiple columns in mysql without creating a temp table

Tags: mysql

I have a data base of about 7 million rows, in those rows I have about 20 columns, three of which have numbers in, but the numbers overlap in the 3 columns and in different position. I have tried a lot of solutions on this site and the best i got was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT res_no FROM gd1file_4_5000000_records
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT mobile_no FROM gd1file_4_5000000_records
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT mobile_no2 FROM gd1file_4_5000000_records
```

This only gave me the count of unique number in one row which i can export, but the rest of the data is not there anymore, names, surname etc. What i need is to keep the data as is, but just remove the duplicates.

So my table looks like this:

```
IDNUM  | INIT     |   FIRST_NAME |  res_no |  mobile_no |  mobile_no2 |
```

So i want to keep the list like this but remove the dupes between `res`, `mobile` and `mobile2`, by just being able to export and not having to change the original file in table.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a temp table? I once worked on an integrity checker, which examined data consistency between two very different schemas, and I was able to realise very large speed increases using temp tables. That was MySQL 4.* if I recall.

Comment: How the desired output would look like?

Comment: To be honest I'm a novice and have been struggling with this for very long.tried different methods and nothing yet. please excuse my ignorance as I'm a complete noob how will I go about this with a temp table? I would like to keep it in the same output as the original.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to solve the problem, it might not be exactly how I wanted to do it but it worked for me.

SELECT max(field1), field2, max(field3),max(field4),max(field5),max(field6),max(field7),max(field8),max(field9),max(field10) FROM table GROUP BY field2;

The only thing is it does not alter the original table, but you can export the result to a new table.